# How to map Stored Procedures with EF4?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, t4, edmx

Is it possible to map stored procédures whit EF 4 using T4 templates ?
I have searched and I conclude that it is not possible yet.

It exist some methods like Edm.SourceComplexTypes(), Edm.SourceAssociations(), Edm.SourceEntities() but nothing about stored procedures ...

Someone have any answer ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did it work, or are you still unable to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing it.  Just open your edmx, right click on the design surface and select Add > Function Import.  You can map the results of the SP to an existing entity or to a new entity type.

After doing this, transform all the templates in the solution and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried it, but I haven't find a way to list the stored procedures in my template.

Comment: @gtoul Not sure what your issue is.  You can import a SP as a function by right-clicking on your EDMX's design surface.  Once you've imported it the SP shows as a function of your data context.